# Java Media Framework x64bit

Tags: java, frameworks, media-player, jmf

I've tried using JMF on a 64 bit environment I didnt find anythere 64 bit jmvfw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Xuggler as Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye said in the first answer or you can also try [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/).

From FMJ site:

```
FMJ is an open-source project with the goal of providing an alternative to Java Media
Framework (JMF), while remaining API-compatible with JMF. It aims to produce a single
API/Framework which can be used to capture, playback, process, and stream media across
multiple platforms.
Since FMJ is API-compatible with latest JMF, you may use existing JMF codes and run the.
```

Comment: Is this a smilar application with JMF?

Comment: ok sandy I download it, I look at the forum for the jmf it has lots of steps for downloading 64 bit etc. I think FMJ is better than it

Comment: I used FMJ for windows as well as Mac. Hope it help you too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no JMF for 64bit environment .But you can try [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2132405) form oracle forum.The other alternative likes JMF is [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler).Try to use it.